# RailsAdmin: How to build nested record with foreign key set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have a `User` class that has_many `Addresses`.

When I am editing the user, and I click to add a new Address in RailsAdmin, I would expect it to build it in the context of that user (since I'm on its page), but it just gives me a dropdown of all users in my system to select from.

[image]

**How can I get RailsAdmin to set the new Address object's `user_id` attribute to the id of the user that I am editing?**

Here's my current config for the users edit action:

```
# this just pretty-prints the address names and also scopes the list down to this specific user
config.model 'User' do
  configure :addresses, :has_many_association

  edit do
    configure :addresses do
      associated_collection_scope do
        user = bindings[:object]
        proc { Address.where(user_id: user) }
      end
    end
  end
end

# I'm guessing something has to get done in here
config.model 'Address' do
  configure :user, :belongs_to_association

  modal do
    configure :user_id do
      default_value do
        # bindings[:object] is an empty Address in this context
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses` to the `User` model.

That changed the edit view to just have a button to add new Addresses and edit the existing addresses related to the record.

No special configuration was necessary in the RailsAdmin initializer.